# Spring Batch and Apache Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch

I am in learning phase of Kafka.I came across this video [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJesCn731G4)

This confuses me alot. I am able to understand kafka consumer and producer and i can see lot of reference materials related to that. We have batch listeners already there so why we need spring batch support here .Is there any specific advantage of using spring kafka batch  over using normal batch listeners? Please help me in understanding as i can't see any reference materials comparing both.What i felt that we have more freedom and customisations using normal consumer and producer.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Batch is a batch processing framework (fixed data sets) while Kafka is a streaming platform (infinite data streams). Those tools address two different types of requirements and use cases.

However, there are many cases where you want to have a "bridge" between these two worlds. Here are a couple examples:

- Replay a stream of events to create an application state up to a certain time: Here you can use a Spring Batch job that reads a Kafka topic from the beginning and replays all events (The `KafkaItemReader` can be helpful here)
- Inject a set of events from a file or a database table in a live stream. The `KafkaItemWriter` can be used in this case.
- etc

The advantage of using a Spring Batch job over a regular batch listener is all what Spring Batch offers in terms of transaction management, state management for restartability, fault-tolerance features, etc.